# Interposition at compile time does not work

Tags: c, function-interposition

I am learning about interposition. The code below is taken from a course (CMU 15-213), however, when I compile, this warning "mymalloc.c:6:29: warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]" occurs.

As I understand, a call to malloc in main() will instead be transferred to the call to mymalloc(). Inside mymalloc(), malloc is called again and hence, the loop occurs.

```
//int.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "malloc.h"

int main() {
    int *p = malloc(32);
    free(p);
    return (0);
}
```

```
//malloc.h

#include <stdlib.h>
#define malloc(size) mymalloc(size)
#define free(ptr) myfree(ptr)

void *mymalloc(size_t size);
void myfree(void *ptr);
```

```
//mymalloc.c

#ifdef COMPILETIME
#include <stdio.h>
#include "malloc.h"

/* malloc wrapper function */
void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    printf("malloc(%d)=%p\n",
           (int)size, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

/* free wrapper function */
void myfree(void *ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
    printf("free(%p)\n", ptr);
}
#endif
```

```
//Makefile

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

intc: int.c mymalloc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DCOMPILETIME -c mymalloc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I. -o intc int.c mymalloc.o

runc:
    ./intc

clean:
    rm -f *~ intr intl intc *.so *.o
```

I tried searching but couldn't find any solution to this problem. Can anyone please help ? Thank you.

Comment: Aside - `printf("malloc(%d)=%p\n", ..` change `%d` to `%zu` and remove the cast to `(int)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote

```
#include "malloc.h"
...
void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
```

which after preprocessing comes out as

```
void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = mymalloc(size);
```

The diagnostic is accurate.
Infinite recursion won't make you happy,
as it will lead to stack overflow.

The `#define malloc(size) mymalloc(size)`
is good for user application code,
but not for the library code you're writing here.
Arrange for application and library source files
to consume appropriate macro definitions.
You might need one more header file, here.

You wrote that both int.c and mymalloc.c
should `#include "malloc.h"`.
No, that cannot be.
The int.c application can consume a `#define`
which changes what "malloc()" means.
But the mymalloc.c library code cannot,
as it must access the original libc malloc routine.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain more on the header file needed to be added ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The `#define malloc(size) mymalloc(size)` in `malloc.h` results in the code `void *ptr = malloc(size);` in `mymalloc.c` being changed to `void *ptr = mymalloc(size);`.

Solutions include:

- Change `void *ptr = malloc(size);` to `void *ptr = (malloc)(size);`. Then, because `malloc` is not followed by a parentheses, the function-like macro will have no effect. Also change `free(ptr);` to `(free)(ptr);`.
- Insert `#undef malloc` after `#include "malloc.h"` in `mymalloc.c`.
- Make a file called `privatemalloc.h` that declares the routines and change `malloc.h` to have `#include "privatemalloc.h"` instead of declaring the routines directly. Then use `#include "privatemalloc.h"` in `mymalloc.c` instead of `#include "malloc.h"`. Continue using `#include "malloc.h"` in other source files. So other source files will get the macro definitions, but `mymalloc.c` will not.
- Change `malloc.h` to define the macros only if some symbol, say `PrivateMalloc`, is not defined. In `mymalloc.c`, insert `#define PrivateMalloc 1` before `#include "malloc.h"`.
- Insert `#define mymalloc malloc` after `#include "malloc.h"` in `mymalloc.c`. When `malloc` is later replaced by `mymalloc`, this `#define` will cause `mymalloc` to be replaced by `malloc`. Macro replacement will then stop, as recursive macro replacements are not performed. Similarly, the `mymalloc` in the source code will be replaced by `malloc` and then `mymalloc`.